# MongoDB syntax error

Tags: json, mongodb, syntax

I am having trouble with the syntax (SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL) in MongoDB. This command was copied directly from a MongoDB instruction PDF and I cannot find out what is wrong.

Also I don't know if it is relevant but I am using Codeanywhere with a MEAN stack.

```
db.restaurants.insert(
    {
        "address" : {
            "street" : "2 Avenue",
            "zipcode" : "10075",
            "building" : "1480",
            "coord" : [ ­73.9557413, 40.7720266 ],
        },
        "borough" : "Manhattan",
        "cuisine" : "Italian",
        "grades" : [
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2014­10­01T00:00:00Z"),
                "grade" : "A",
                "score" : 11
            },
            {
                "date" : ISODate("2014­01­16T00:00:00Z"),
                "grade" : "B",
                "score" : 17
            }
        ],
        "name" : "Vella",
        "restaurant_id" : "41704620"
    }
)
```

Comment: You have a surplus comma after the `coord` array. Should be`"coord" : [ ­73.9557413, 40.7720266 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
"coord" : [ ­73.9557413, 40.7720266 ],
```

with:

```
"coord" : [ ­73.9557413, 40.7720266 ]
```

The comma at the end of subdocument is extra.

By the way, the JSON standard allows only double quoted string as property key, thus, try also this variant:

```
"coord" : [ "­73.9557413", "40.7720266" ]
```

I checked your entire JSON-document with a JSON validator, here is a valid version:

```
{
    "address": {
        "street": "2 Avenue",
        "zipcode": "10075",
        "building": "1480",
        "coord": ["73.9557413", "40.7720266"]
    },
    "borough": "Manhattan",
    "cuisine": "Italian",
    "grades": [{
        "date": "20141001T00:00:00Z",
        "grade": "A",
        "score": 11
    }, {
        "date": "20140116T00:00:00Z",
        "grade": "B",
        "score": 17
    }],
    "name": "Vella",
    "restaurant_id": "41704620"
}
```

Comment: Ok so i removed the surplus comma, and its still giving me the same error. I went over the commas and brackets and I don't see anything else. Does indentation play a role here or no?

Comment: Thanks Mike, yep that is correct I was trying to figure out why it was giving me (invalid ISO date at src/mongo/shell/types.js:64) I deleted the ISODate and everything is dandy.